# How to deploy WordPress content from Dev to Staging to Production environments?

Tags: php, wordpress

We inherited a WordPress website and set up Dev, Staging and Production environments. Deploying code changes to each environment (e.g. going from Dev to Staging) has been simple to do by putting the code in Git.

However, we're not sure how to do the same with WordPress content that lives in the database and files in the wp-content/uploads directory.

We'd like to use our Dev site as the source of truth, prepare content changes in there, and then deploy those content changes to Staging and Production, just like we would do with code.

Some of the situations we have to handle:

- Only deploying content (and not users) from one environment to another
- Being able to deploy changes live outside the `wp_posts` table. For example, if we change menus in Appearance > Menus, that's stored elsewhere in the WordPress DB.
- Making sure that any hard-coded absolute URLs (e.g. in images, links, widgets, etc) are not deployed with hard-coded domains (e.g. dev.mydomain.com)

Is there a standardized way to handle a content deployment pipeline in WordPress from Dev to Staging to Production?

We're looking at plugins, but none of them seem to achieve this to a full extent.

Thanks

Comment: I think WP Migrate DB pro can handle your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an ETL (Extract - Transform - Load) script most likely. It would pull the tables you want. Extract -

- Wp_posts
- wp_postmeta
- wp_terms
- wp_termmeta
- wp_term_taxonomy
- wp_term_relationships
- any plugin tables not in the wp core.

Or you could probably take all tables excluding:

- wp_users
- wp_usermeta
- wp_options

Then run a search and replace for absolute urls.

Finally load the tables into the next environment.

You can write it manually or use a program like [Talend Open Studio for Big Data](https://www.talend.com/landing-download/ppc/tos-big-data/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=NA%20Search%20-%20Branded%20-%20General&utm_term=talend&utm_content=talend%20-%20exact&utm_creative=272909373253&lang=en&src=GoogleAdwordsOD_US&kid=null&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIjKCAuYjN5wIVlf_jBx1XIAjaEAAYASABEgK8l_D_BwE)